# How to add a service account (sp_c2wts) to local security policy using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a powershell way to achieve this? I have to do this for 40 servers.

Set the following permissions on all SharePoint servers in the farm (All must be done) – this is completed under Local Security Policy (gpedit.msc as administrator -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies > User rights assignment) on each server

[print shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrpGR.png)

Grant Log on as a service

Impersonate a User

Act as part of the operating system

Comment: This may be the solution. I will post my findings in few minutes. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solution worked perfectly.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.